# easiest and fastest way to sort an arraylist containing strings like "0.222:Hello test" by its float?

Tags: java

im trying for a few days now to sort an arraylist which consist out of these 
strings(by its float at the beginning of the list):
"0.1:test1"
"0.11:test2"
"0.21:test3"
"0.14:test4"
"2.1:test5"
i wasn't able to find a way, the closest attempt was with collections.sort
but it only sorted the list by its first number which isn't what im looking for:/

could someone help me out? thanks a lot in advance, this site has helped me a lot with my java hobby projects already:)

```
    Collections.sort(arrayList1);
    Collections.reverse(arrayList1);
    for (String value : arrayList1){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

sorted by first number not by full number

Comment: Since the slowest part is the parsing of the float, start by converting the list of string into list of objects, the sort the objects by the float value, and convert back to list of strings when done. That is likely the *fastest* way, but certainly not the *easiest* way, which do you prefer, easy or fast?

Comment: thanks for your fast answer! im looking for this: {"0.1:test1", "0.11:test2",  "0.14:test4", "0.21:test3","2.1:test5"}   i would love to have the optimal code for fast and efficient sorting, the main goal for this code is to have an easy chance based sytem like for video games where you can get something by chance 50% e.g.

Comment: It sounds like you truly have a new type. You should create a class expressing this type, have it implement Comparable, and create your own compare method. Then you can just run it through any sort you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("0.1:test1", "0.11:test2", "0.21:test3", "0.14:test4", "2.1:test5");

list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> Double.parseDouble(s.split(":", 2)[0])));

System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[0.1:test1, 0.11:test2, 0.14:test4, 0.21:test3, 2.1:test5]
```

With the `split` and the `parseDouble` calls inside the `compare` method, it is certainly not the *fastest* solution, but it is the *easiest*.

Comment: wow! thanks for your fast help!:) i try to implement it and to get familar with it, thanks a lot Andreas! is there an faster way to do it? i want to have close to 100 'strings' in the list, could i also use a treeMap?

Comment: @meow Have you tried it with 100 strings? Was that too slow for you? Takes about 0.1 *millisecond* on my PC.